# How can I visit my node server via https?

Tags: nginx, https, koa

I simply code a node server with koa, I can start it with `npm start` and visit it through `localhost:3000` for example.

Now I want to visit it through `https://www.test.com`. I use Nginx for reverse proxy, and now I can visit it through `www.test.com`. **But how can I visit it through https://www.test.com?**

Please give me some advice, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is via [CloudFlare](https://cloudflare.com), which will provide a free HTTPS proxying layer in front of your website. You don't need to set up certificates locally, CloudFlare will automatically obtain them for your domain.

Answer (score 0):

[you have to configure your NGINX server to use HTTPS](http://www.nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html)

And also you need valid HTTPS certificates. Also make a rule to redirect everything from http to https , or only for a specific domain, there are plenty of examples how to do that.